# Selenium how to identify an object by its type?

Tags: selenium

In Selenium is it possible to identify the object by its type?
e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="FirstName" value="">
```

Here can I identity the above element by its type of "text"?

Comment: Please do one question at a time.  I also added code tagging as the code wasn't showing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A slightly different interpretation of the question just in case :)

Lets say you have already located one or more elements in your test and you want to identify them by their 'type' html attribute...

```
// Lets locate the first found input tag
WebElement someElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input")); 

// And now lets store it's type
String typeOfElement = someElement.getAttribute("type");
```

Or if you want to deal with a list of elements

```
// Locate all input tags on the page
List<WebElement> someElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input")); 

// Now iterate through them and check for our desired match
for (WebElement anElement : someElements) {
    if (anElement.getAttribute("type").equals("text")) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Below are the answer to your questions.

> In Selenium is it possible to identify the object by its type. Ex;
>   Here do we able to identity above object by its type call text.

Yes, it is possible to identify the objects by its type. As already mentioned by @Michael Durrant, you can use the CssSelector for that.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='text']"));
```

> Then do we able to count how may object were on the page where its
>   type is text. Lets say some time page may contain more than one object
>   which type is text. So I need the count in that case.

Yes, this too is possible using Selenium. You need to use the following code for that.

```
int i = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='text']")).size(); //this will provide the number of elements with mentioned type
System.out.println(i);
```

> Finally do we able to do separate action after identify those objects.
>   Lest say i need to enter difference values into text fields.

This you can do in a multiple ways:

**Solution 1:** Using the index of the elements. Once you know the number of elements you can set different value of each element using their index position e.g.

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='text']")).get(1).sendKeys("Name");
```

Remember, index of elements will start from '0', so if there are 4 elements on your page; then their indexes will be 0, 1, 2, 3

**Solution 2:** Store your elements to a Array list and then set value of these list elements. You can use CSV/Excel or any other external file too for setting value of these list elements.

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='text']")).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indentify a page element like that with  a css selector

```
input[type='text']
```

Answer (score 0):

Identifying an object by its type attribute in Selenium is definitely possible. You can use the `By.cssSelector()` method to locate the element with a specific type. Here's an example:

```
// Find the first input element with type attribute as "text"
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='text']"));

// Count the number of input elements with type attribute as "text"
int count = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='text']")).size();
System.out.println("Number of input elements with type attribute as 'text': " + count);

// Enter values into each input element with type attribute as "text"
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='text']"));
for (WebElement el : elements) {
    el.sendKeys("some value");
}
```

In the above example, we first locate the element with a specific type attribute by using the `By.cssSelector()` method. We can also count the number of elements with the same type attribute by using `driver.findElements()` method and `size()` method. Finally, we can enter values into each input element with the same type attribute by using a `for` loop and `sendKeys()` method.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.